# How to make Intellij IDEA 13 debug node.js application?

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

My problem specifically is depicted below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=60953 --nolazy bin\www
Debugger listening on port 60953
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markk\Documents\work\q\internal\freelist.js']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'c:\\Users\\markk\\Documents\\work\\q\\internal\\freelist.js' }
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markk\Documents\work\q\internal\child_process.js']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'c:\\Users\\markk\\Documents\\work\\q\\internal\\child_process.js' }
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markk\Documents\work\q\internal\socket_list.js']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'c:\\Users\\markk\\Documents\\work\\q\\internal\\socket_list.js' }
```

And this happens with the default Node.js+Express.js project I created. As a result the IDE does not debug the node javascript code.

I found this - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1328, which seems relevant, but I do not understand how does it apply to IntelliJ IDEA 13.

Comment: The link you posted links to [this webstorm issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16256) which seems fixed sometime in 2015, while (if I recall correctly) 13.1.7 is dated EOY 2014. It's not really the answer one would expect, but can you try with a newer IJ version (maybe 30 day ultimate trial)?

Comment: Yes, I have already realized that my version is not good. Kinda sucks. I guess I will have to upgrade. Thanks.